# How not to show leave a Reply to Home Page?

Tags: homepage

I have made my Front Page as a Static Page. The Page is having a Introduction Content. I am showing this content as an introduction to the site. But it displays "Leave a Reply" Box below it. I do not want the users to give comments on this content. Can somebody suggest How to suppress this for my Static Home Page for all users except Admin.

Comment: show us the code you are using so I can tell you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to 'Pages'.
2. Look for the page you've set as your homepage in the list.
3. Hover your cursor over the title and click on 'Quick Edit'.
4. Uncheck 'Allow Comments' and then 'Update'.

**Edit:**
For disabling Trackbacks and Pingbacks (and Comments too!):

1. Open the page you've set as your homepage for editing.
2. Look for a box titled 'Discussion', and uncheck 'Allow Pingbacks and Trackbacks on this page'.
3. If the 'Discussion' box is not visible on the edit page, then click on the 'Screen Options' button which is at the very top (near 'Howdy Admin'). Select 'Discussion' from the panel.
4. Now repeat step 2.

Hope this helps! If it's not clear, please let me know, I'll put a screen shot.

Comment: It now says "Comments are closed, but trackbacks and pingbacks are open" I just wanted it to look like a Introductory Text" without anything showing below it.

Comment: Okay... Editing my answer...

Comment: Please check my original answer again.